# Tire depth is 4, is it safe to drive?

Tags: tires

when took my car for oil change, mechanic said that the tire Threads are too thin to drive , less than 5. So it is not safe to drive. Till what depth we can drive the car safely. Tires also has some minor cracks.

Comment: 4 what? 4 millimeters? This should be covered by law. In my country the legal safety limit for winter tires is 3 mm, and for regular tires - 1.6 mm. So 4 mm is not unsafe, but you should start looking for tires.

Comment: If the road is perfectly dry, you would get the best grip with no tread at all - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Racing_slick .  However most of us live in countries that have laws that dictate the minimum tread thickness, so you need to look into the law in your country/local area.

Comment: If it's 4/32" (3.17mm), you should consider getting new tires soon.

Answer (score 4):

According to [TireRack.com](http://www.tirerack.com/tires/tiretech/techpage.jsp?techid=163&):

> In most parts of the world, tires are considered to be legally worn out when they reach 2/32" (approximately 1.6mm) of remaining tread depth. U.S. law requires tires to have easy-to-see Tread Wear Indicator bars running from one side of their tread design to the other when the tire's tread has worn down to the minimum legal limit of 2/32 inch.

Tread wear indicator bars on a partially worn tire:

[image: Tread wear indicator]

[They also state](http://blog.tirerack.com/blog/tire-rack-team-blog/new-year-new-tires):

> ... if snow-covered roads are a concern, it’s time to replace your tires when they reach approximately 6/32” of remaining tread depth. For rain and wet roads, you should consider replacing your tires when they reach approximately 4/32” of remaining tread depth.

While you can *possibly* get away with running tread that thin, it really isn't advised to do so. The place where you got your oil changed at is right in suggesting you get new tires, but they are still legal. My suggestion is to invest in some new tires soon, especially with the winter months fast approaching.